# Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore

Tags: jmeter

Can someone help me with the integration of the .pfx client certificate with the jmeter ?
I have converted the pfx file into jks file. I have added the same in the system.properties . But I am no able to execute the client request. I get the following error.

2018-11-08 22:31:08,137 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: C:MyWorkSpace/apache-jmeter-5.0certclientcert.jks type jks
2018-11-08 22:31:08,137 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2018-11-08 22:31:08,137 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2018-11-08 22:31:08,137 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)

Please guide me if I am missing any steps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your log file JMeter tries to locate the keystore under the following path:

```
C:MyWorkSpace/apache-jmeter-5.0certclientcert.jks
```

which doesn't look a valid one to me. Try replacing all backslashes `\` with forward ones `/` in the path so it would look like:

```
C:/MyWorkSpace/apache-jmeter-5.0/certclientcert.jks
```

Another option is to specify the path to the keystore in [*system.properties*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) file like:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/MyWorkSpace/apache-jmeter-5.0/certclientcert.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_password
```

And last but not the least, you can pass the path to the keystore via [-D command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/MyWorkSpace/apache-jmeter-5.0/certclientcert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_password -n -t test.jmx ...
```

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)